# create more lists from one big list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, split

I have the following list which was created from a text file  that I already have.

In the end I have a list that contains all the values that I need from the text, and now I am trying to have a more than one small lists from the list array where every small list start with switch and end where the value is empty.

```
with open("read.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('switch '):
            array.append(line)
            for line in f:  # Continue iterating f for additional lines to keep
                if not line.rstrip():
                    break  # We hit an empty line, return to looking for switch
                array.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
i = 0
while i+4 <= len(my_list):
    print(my_list[i+1:i+4])
    i+=4
#['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
#['m1', 'm2', 'm3']
```